# A regex to get string out of the brackets?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following string:

> "The girl with the dragon tattoo (LISBETH)"

and I need to get **only the string in the brackets** at the end of the input.

So far I came to this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pattern pattern =
    Pattern.compile("\\({1}([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\\){1}");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("The girl with the dragon tattoo (LISBETH)");

    boolean found = false;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("I found the text " + matcher.group()
                + " starting at " + "index " + matcher.start()
                + " and ending at index " +
                matcher.end());
        found = true;
    }
    if (!found) {
        System.out.println("No match found");
    }
}
```

But as a result I get: `(LISBETH)`.

How to get away from those brackets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use look behind and look ahead, then you don't need to use/access the groups

```
Pattern.compile("(?<=\\()[a-zA-Z0-9]*(?=\\))");
```

Those look behind/ahead are not matching, they are just "checking", so those brackets will not be part of the match.

Comment: +1, but isn't the positive look behind with an equals sign `(?<=\\()`?

Comment: General tip of mine: *Don't use lookarounds when you don't need to.* Not only does it complicate the expression unnecessarily but it's also plain wrong in some cases. In this case it will work fine, but for example if you would lookarounds to find quoted substrings, eg `(?<=")[^"]*(?=")` you'd get invalid results. In `"foo" bar "baz"` it would find `foo`, ` bar ` and `baz`.

Comment: I don't think that lookarounds complicate the expression, of course you need to know how they work. And I agree with you, in this case they are difficult, since they don't "consume" the quotes, the regex would match wrong in your example.

Answer (score 10):

Use this pattern: `\\((.+?)\\)` and then get the group 1

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.+?)\\)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("The girl with the dragon tattoo (LISBETH)");

    boolean found = false;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("I found the text " + matcher.group(1)
                + " starting at " + "index " + matcher.start()
                + " and ending at index " +
                matcher.end());
        found = true;
    }
    if (!found) {
        System.out.println("No match found");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but - again - I get (LISBETH). I need only LISBETH as a result.

Comment: are you sure? did you save file before compiling? Because i just copied this method to my project and it works normally.

Answer (score 3):

You are really close, just change `group()`, `start()` and `end()` calls to `group(1)`, `start(1)` and `end(1)` since you already have it in a "matching group".

Quoted from the api:

> public String group()
>
> Returns the input subsequence matched by the previous match.

And:

> public String group(int group)
>
> Returns the input subsequence captured by the given group during the previous match operation.